# Trying to exit While True loop but it won't

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

I wanted it to print out the date and stop but it would keep printing "Enter: " even though there is "break" and it printed out the date successfully.

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter: ")
    if "/" not in user:
        if "," in user:
            date = user.replace(",", "")
        date = date.split(" ")
        date = list(date)
        for i in range(len(date)):
            if date[i] in month:
                mnth = month[f"{date[i]}"]
                if int(date[1]) < 10:
                    date[1] = "0" + date[1]
                print(f"{date[2]}-{mnth}-{date[1]}")
                break
```

Comment: You can only beak out of the innermost loop. So that breaks out of the `for` loop, not the `while` loop.

Comment: If you want `break` to break out of the `while True` loop, you need to align it the same as `user = input("Enter: ")`.

Comment: `date = list(date)` is unnecessary. `split()` returns a list.

Comment: Why are you looping over `date`, but then using hard-coded indexes inside the loop? What exactly is this code trying to do?

Comment: It prints dates as year-month-date format. It loops over date so that it checks if there is a month in it and checks if that month is in a dictionary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only break out of the innermost loop directly, you need to use a variable to tell the outer loop to stop.

```
done = False
while not done:
    user = input("Enter: ")
    if "/" not in user:
        date = user.replace(",", "")
        date = date.split(" ")
        for i in range(len(date)):
            if date[i] in month:
                mnth = month[f"{date[i]}"]
                if int(date[1]) < 10:
                    date[1] = "0" + date[1]
                print(f"{date[2]}-{mnth}-{date[1]}")
                done = True
                break
```

I also got rid of the unneeded `date = list(date)`.

The `if "," in user:` check shouldn't be done, because you never set `date` if there's no `,` to replace. Just call `replace()` and if there aren't any `,` it will return the string unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

One way to break an outer loop from an inner loop without adding an extra variable to keep track of is to use `else: continue` followed by a `break`:

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter: ")
    if "/" not in user:
        if "," in user:
            date = user.replace(",", "")
        date = date.split(" ")
        date = list(date)
        for i in range(len(date)):
            if date[i] in month:
                mnth = month[f"{date[i]}"]
                if int(date[1]) < 10:
                    date[1] = "0" + date[1]
                print(f"{date[2]}-{mnth}-{date[1]}")
                break
        else:
            continue  # continue if the for loop wasn't broken
        break         # break the while if we didn't continue
```

As explained in the comments, the trick is that the `else` of the `for` executes if there was no `break` -- we can therefore `continue` the `while` if and only if there was no `break` inside the `for`, and explicitly `break` the `while` otherwise.

Not directly related to that, I'd suggest battling some of that indentation by using `continue` elsewhere in the loop, and getting rid of all the unnecessary string manipulation (note the use of `{date[1]:0>2}` to zero-pad to two digits without needing the int math -- neat, eh?):

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter: ")
    if "/" in user:
        continue
    date = user.replace(",", "").split(" ")
    for mm in date:
        if mm not in month:
            continue
        print(f"{date[2]}-{mm}-{date[1]:0>2}")
        break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

and since your code seems to assume that `date[2]` is always the year and `date[1]` is always the day of the month, I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you can also safely assume the month is always `date[0]` if it's anything at all, which means you can skip that whole inner loop and just do:

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter: ")
    if "/" in user:
        continue
    mm, dd, yyyy = user.replace(",", "").split(" ")[:3]
    if mm not in month:
        continue
    print(f"{yyyy}-{mm}-{dd:0>2}")
    break
```